# Detect bad USB cable

Tags: command-line, usb

Is it possible to detect with confidence via command line that the USB cable is damaged? I tried to connect my printer and it's not printing with this cable, I guess that the culprit is the USB cable.

The only command I know is `lsusb` but I don't know how to use it to detect this type of information.

I have only one cable now (and USB mouse and keyboard, it they could help) and I'd like to test if the cable is damaged. Is there a procedure I can do and say after it: "The USB cable should go to garbage"

[image: USB cable]

Answer (score 4):

This might sound a bit old school, but by far the easiest way is to use another USB cable and see if the problem persists.

If it does, the cable almost certainly is not at fault

Answer (score 4):

It is not really possible to easily determine whether it is the device or the cable at fault at the client, as both often manifest with similar symptoms. Probably the best way to do this is to simply try another USB cable. In most cases the USB cable is little more than a dumb pipe between the device and the client -- it's all but invisible to the operating system, other than the fact that the OS may know if it is connected and/or receiving data from/transmitting data to it.

The edit to your question stating that you have only one USB cable leaves another option: try the cable with another device.